# Unable to Load persisted workflow with work flow Instance Id in WF 4.5

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity, workflow-foundation-4.5

**'EnvironmentLocationReference' is not of type 'InternalState'. When loading this instance you must ensure that the activity with name 'EnvironmentLocationReference' implements 'InternalState'.**

Please help to resolve this.

Getting Exception in 
workflowapplication wfapp=new workflowapplication(new workflowDefinition);
wfappp.Load(wfId, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));

wfid(workflow id) which is saved in persistance database

Comment: EnvironmentLocationReference must implement InternalState.  So implement it.

Comment: I am unable to find EnvironmentLocationReference in my solution

Comment: Hmmmm, good point.  That is weird.

Comment: Now I found EnvironmentLocationReference in dynamicupdatemap.map file but with                           “Cannot remove activity ‘1.131:” 'EnvironmentLocationReference<String>’ because it is currently Executing
“Cannot remove activity ‘1.142:” 'EnvironmentLocationReference<String>’ because it is currently Executing   exception